# Crystal Report Parameter suppression reference

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, optional-parameters, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm suppressing these fields:
 if ({?Status}= "APPROVED") and isnull({Command.APPROVED}) then true
else
if ({?Status}= "QUOTED") and isnull({Command.QUOTED}) then true

I need to add another statement that says else "ALL" to include all possible data from both the Command.APPROVED and Command.QUOTED regardless of values.

Comment: It's not perfectly clear what you're asking. Could you maybe include an image? Or at least go into more detail about what you want to display if the user selects X or Y?

Answer (score 0):

To suppress, use something like this:

```
(
  {?Status}= "APPROVED" and isnull({Command.APPROVED})
) 
OR 
(
  {?Status}= "QUOTED") and isnull({Command.QUOTED})
)
```

To Filter Records, use something like this:

```
(
   {?Status} <> "APPROVED" OR NOT isnull({Command.APPROVED})
) 
AND 
(
   {?Status} <> "QUOTED") OR NOT isnull({Command.QUOTED})
)
```